# in 8051 unable to dump the hex file

Tags: c, embedded, hex, uart, 8051

I have written a UART TX code in C .The data is  transmitting using a while (1) loop . Since the Controller is busy all the time  in only transmitting the data I'm unable to dump any new hex file on to the chip .Its always telling communication failed .

```
#include <reg51.h>
void inituart(void);
void Tx_Data(unsigned char);
void SCI_String_Tx(unsigned char *string);
void delay_ms(unsigned char milliseconds);

   void delay_ms(unsigned char ms)
   {
       unsigned char t1;
       unsigned int t2;

for(t1=0; t1<ms; t1++){
    for(t2=0; t2<711; t2++);
      }
   }

void inituart()
{
    TMOD=0X21;
    SCON=0X50;
    TH1=0XFD;
    TR1=1;

}


void SCI_String_Tx(unsigned char *string) 
{
    while(*string)
    {
        Tx_Data(*(string++));
    }
}

void Tx_Data(unsigned char v)
{
     SBUF=v;
     while(TI==0);
     TI=0;
}


void main(void)
{
    inituart();
        while (1)
        {   
            delay_ms(1000);
            SCI_String_Tx("HELLO WORLD!"); //Data to terminal
            delay_ms(1000);
            delay_ms(10);
        }

 }
```

Comment: I don't recall a stock standard 8051 having any on-chip memory (though it's been a while since I programmed these beasts). Are you sure you're not using a more advanced variant, like something from Dallas Semi? If you are, it changes how you can wipe the memory. If not, you can probably just replace the rom/prom/eprom/eeprom/etc).

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. By "dump the hex file" - do you mean "program the part"?  How are you programming the part?  For example via JTAG or a serial bootloader perhaps? And with what tools? If using a serial bootloader, it will generally run when the chip is booted, so performing a power-on reset after starting the download may work.  It really depends on the exact part you are using (8051 defines just the core architecture - Intel no longer make these parts), and what tool-chain you are using.  This is probably not an SO question as your code is not the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Do you mean you want to download program into the MCU chip?

There arm many ways to do that, such as: isp, jtag, uart...

You can check the details from the chip's DATASHEET.

Comment: Request for clarification should be posted as a comment not an answer.